# Confused about writing a media converter

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I want to write my own media converter application using ffmpeg. I have a couple of questions

1. Can I use a command line to make the conversion. I don't think that would work if the user hasn't installed ffmpeg on to his system. If that's the case, how'd I overcome it. I don't believe their API has anything for media conversion.
2. Is it possible to write it in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide an ffmeg binary with your application, and use the [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and/or [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class to invoke it. You would need a different binary for each OS you intend to target though.